# Formula result used for column reference ID

Tags: excel, function

I want to consolidate the data of a graph. The graphs length is not consistent, so I used this to find the end of the page:

`=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))`

I need to use the result from this in the reference field so Excel knows the range of the it is consolidating. I just need the right syntax.

Here's an example of what I want:

`$B14:$D$[result of formula]`

The [result of formula] being the number gotten from SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find the range from B14 to the last number in column D.

```
$B$14:index(D:D, match(1e99, $D:$D))
'proof it like
=sum($B$14:index(D:D, match(1e99, $D:$D)))
```

You should find it a lot less calculation intensive than SUMPRODUCT with a full column reference.

Your own formula would likely have to involve INDIRECT like,

```
INDIRECT("B14:D" & SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))))
```

Comment: What I was asking for is how to properly use a formula, or the result of whatever formula, in the reference field in consolidate.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't see your edit. Your solution for SUMPRODUCT did not give a correct result. So, for now, I'll be using SUMPRODUCT. Also, for some reason, INDIRECT is doubling the result of the consolidation.